# find text by grep and replace path of that with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have *.dot file, for example:

```
...
0 -> 1 [color=black];
1 -> 2 [color=blue];
1 -> 3 [color=blue];
2 -> 4 [color=gold3];
..
```

I need to change "color" of lines whose started with $a number. I can easy get `=blue` using

```
a="1"
cat experimental.dot | grep "^$a\ ->" | grep -o =[a-Z0-9]*
```

But i can't change `=blue` to `=red` in file using sed.

Comment: FYI, `[a-Z,0-9]` doesn't do what you think it does. In particular, it will match a comma in the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a=1
sed "/^$a /s/\\(color=\\)[[:alnum:]]\\+/\\1red/" <<END
0 -> 1 [color=black];
1 -> 2 [color=blue];
1 -> 3 [color=blue];
2 -> 4 [color=gold3];
END
```

```
0 -> 1 [color=black];
1 -> 2 [color=red];
1 -> 3 [color=red];
2 -> 4 [color=gold3];
```

For all lines beginning with your variable value (adding the space so you don't match "10" or "11") change the word following "color=" to red.

Comment: sed -i "/^$id /s/\\(color=\\)[[:alnum:]]\\+/color=$2/"  experimental.dot
I stopped on this variant, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It probably should be like this:

```
a="1"
sed "/^$a ->/s/=blue/=red/" experimental.dot
```

Output:

```
0 -> 1 [color=black];
1 -> 2 [color=red];
1 -> 3 [color=red];
2 -> 4 [color=gold3];
```

If you want to modify the file, use `-i`:

```
sed -i "/^$a ->/s/=blue/=red/" experimental.dot
```